# How can I get the total objects returned in Django queryset within my aggregation?

Tags: python, django

If I have a model:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

And I do a query:

```py
Book.objects.filter(name__icontains="The").aggregate(number_of_books=Count("*"), ...)
```

Here, I'm filtering the books to only return ones that contain the `The` substring, and doing an aggregation. I want the resulting dict to tell me, among other things, how many items were in my queryset. This should be the same as if I did `Book.objects.filter(name__icontainers="The").count()`.

What will get me the total number of items (Books) in my queryset? `Count("*")` was just a guess, but it seems to work. Is that correct?

Comment: i usually just count the PK of the models, so in your case would be like `Count("book_id")`

Comment: @NightOwl I see. Does `Count("*")` do the same thing, or is it doing something different?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, correct me if I'm wrong, or if you're doing something extra here, but one can simply:

```
 Book.objects.filter(name__icontains="The").count()
```

Which returns an integer which is the length of the queryset you've filtered.

`.count()` isn't heavy on resources, so if you need to have both an aggregated queryset AND the count, just make two queries to the database, one for your count, and the other your aggregated queryset.

Comment: I'm basically just trying to save the extra query, and have everything I need available in the resulting dict. `Count("*")` from my example seems to work, and is super simple, but I have no idea if it's doing what I think it's doing, or if it's counting something else, and the numbers in my limited testing just happen to line up